# How do I bind current logged user id and pass it to the create method in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Table called `Advertisement` and it's got number of columns including `UserId` reference to it as a foreign key. That is references the `AspNetUsers` table ID column. This table is the one creates with the project itself.

I have created Advertisement table and user CRUD for creating Controller and View to update the table. When it's creating the view it created a dropdown list where I have to select the current logged user. But I want to get the current user id from `User.Identity.GetUserID` and assign it to the `UserId` field and post it to the create method so that It saves in the `Advertisement` table.

**How do I do this? How do I bind a value to it rather than selecting from the drop down list?**

Sorry since I am new to this MVC I may have explained it wrong. If this is not clear to you I can give more details on my problem.

See here for part of my view

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "UserId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("UserId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

My Controller Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AdId,AdTitle,AdDesc1,AdDesc2,PostCode,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,DoorNumber,SubCatId,UserId")] Advertisement advertisement)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Advertisements.Add(advertisement);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "Email", advertisement.UserId);
        ViewBag.SubCatId = new SelectList(db.SubCategories, "SubCatId", "SubCatDesc", advertisement.SubCatId);
        return View(advertisement);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I bind a value to [a model property] rather than selecting from the drop down list?

In your controller action for the GET (your code only shows the POST), simply set the `model.UserId` to the value you want it to be and use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.UserId)
```

rather than the `DropDownList`.  You could use `DropDownListFor` if you still want to show it / allow it to be changed or `@Html.Hidden("UserID")` if you don't want it bound to a property on your viewmodel.

> I want to get the current user id from User.Identity.GetUserID ... post it to the create method so that it saves in the Advertisement table.

Why not use `User.Identity.GetUserID` directly in the POST action?

If this is what you're trying to do, there doesn't seem any need to pass it via the view.   In the controller, the current user is `User.Identity.Name`

I might be missing something here...